# HttpWebRequest file uploading

Tags: c#

I have this code which is meant to upload a file to a Discord server via a webhook:

```cs
string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("uri");
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
request.Method = "POST";

Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

var boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
var endBoundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--");

string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.exe\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

request.Headers.Add(headerTemplate);
```

but it is throwing an exception

> Exception Unhandled error, 'Specified value has invalid CRLF characters.' File Path is at %userprofile%\Desktop\test.exe

Comment: Are you sure you've shown the relevant code? What is the full exception text?

Comment: CRLF stands for linefeed characters like \r\n. Just a wild guess but the request may not support the characters "\r\n" try to replace them with "Environment.NewLine".